# Reverse Engineering of MMA `Classify[]` Output?

Tags: machine-learning, undocumented

**Update**: as @AntonAntoniv rightly noticed in his comment the [case of DecisionTree](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180719/how-to-inspect-the-learned-classifierfunction-decision-tree-model) is already discussed. Now it would be great to also have an equivalent answer for **LogisticRegression**.

---

MMA is really convenient to test/check various classiers, like DecisionTree, LogisticRegression, etc.. By example:

```
iris = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "FisherIris"}, "Data"];
data = GroupBy[iris, Last -> First];
c = Classify[data, Method -> "DecisionTree"];
cm = ClassifierMeasurements[c, data];
cm["ConfusionMatrixPlot"]
```

[image]

Now suppose that I want to reuse the classifier elsewhere (for instance in a C++ code), is there any documentation about how to retrieve the relevant information like: tree structure, thresholds... etc?

I can do

```
c // InputForm
```

which prints a lot of information:

> ClassifierFunction[<|"ExampleNumber" -> 150, "ClassNumber" -> 3,
>   "Input" -> <|"Preprocessor" ->
>   MachineLearning`MLProcessor["ToMLDataset", <|"Input" -> <|"f1" ->
>   <|"Type" -> "NumericalVector", "Length" -> 4|>|>, 
>   "Output" -> <|"f1" -> <|"Type" -> "NumericalVector", "Weight" -> 1|>|>, "Preprocessor" -> MachineLearning`MLProcessor["Sequence", 
>   <|"Processors" -> {MachineLearning`MLProcessor["List"], MachineLearning`MLProcessor["WrapMLDataset", <|"FeatureTypes" ->
>   {"NumericalVector"}, "FeatureKeys" -> {"f1"}, "FeatureWeights" ->
>   Automatic, 
>   "ExampleWeights" -> Automatic, "RawExample" -> Missing["KeyAbsent", "RawExample"]|>]}|>], "ScalarFeature" -> True,
>   "Invertibility" -> "Perfect", "Missing" -> "Allowed"|>], 
>   "Processor" -> MachineLearning`MLProcessor["Sequence", <|"Input" -> <|"f1" -> <|"Type" -> "NumericalVector", "Weight" -> 1|>|>, "Output" -> <|"f1" -> <|"Type" -> "NumericalVector", "Weight" ->
>   1|>|>, 
>   "Processors" -> {MachineLearning`MLProcessor["ImputeMissing", <|"Invertibility" -> "Perfect", "Missing" -> "Imputed", "Input" ->
>   <|"f1" -> <|"Type" -> "NumericalVector", "Weight" -> 1|>|>, 
>     "VectorLength" -> 4, "Imputer" -> (DimensionReducerFunction[<|"ExampleNumber" -> 150, "Imputer" ->
>   MachineLearning`MLProcessor["ImputeMissing", <|"Invertibility" ->
>   "Perfect", "Missing" -> "Imputed", 
>   "Input" -> <|"f1" -> <|"Type" -> "NumericalVector", "Weight" -> 1|>|>, "VectorLength" -> 4, "Naive" -> True, "Fill" ->
>   {5.843333333333335, 3.057333333333334, 3.7580000000000027, 
>                       1.199333333333334}, "Output" -> <|"f1" -> <|"Type" -> "NumericalVector", "Weight" -> 1|>|>, "Type" -> "NumericalVector"|>], "Preprocessor" ->
>   MachineLearning`MLProcessor["ToMLDataset",
>
> ....
>
> ... a long list ....
>
> ....

but AFAIK this structure is not documented.

In short is it possible the do "reverse engineering" of `Classify` function output? (I am espcially interested by DecitionTree and LogisticRegression).

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["How to inspect the learned ClassifierFunction decision tree model?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180719/34008) or ["How to extract tree parameters from RandomForest?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155518/34008). Because of this I am voting to close, but I do not feel that strongly about it, ~70%.

Comment: @AntonAntonov I was not aware of this, thanks! This is not a "perfect" duplicate as I also would be interesting in interpreting the structure in case of LogisticRegression. I can update my post in this sense.

Comment: Ok, I retracted my close vote.